# Invalid CSS property value: spin 2s infinite linear for Font Awesome

Tags: css, fonts

I've included Font Awesome 4.0.3 in my website and everything is fine, except a warning in Chrome version 31.0.1650.57 for Mac: "Invalid CSS property value: spin 2s infinite linear" which points to font-awesome.min.css file. This is css link that I've used in website's head which seems simple enough:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I linked font-awesome.css with no luck. Does anyone know how can I fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the animation still occurring?

Comment: @Zeaklous I tried animation now. It's showing. This is website that I'm working on: http://hosting.ehsanabbasi.com

Comment: The only warning I'm getting is `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.` Does that mean your problem solved itself?

Comment: @Zeaklous No. Other than that I still get that warning. It's weird